# Automatically configure Outlook profile for new users on Citrix server

Tags: outlook, citrix, profile

I would like to setup the default profile on our Citrix server so that when a new user is granted access, their profile is already/automatically configured to point towards our exchange server. The correct exchange server address will vary depending on the user's domain.

I have read about office resource kit providing some way to do this but have not found a simple walkthrough.  I am not an SA, just someone who has been tasked with figuring this out.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Office are you using?

Check out the whitepaper in this link:  Outlook Deployment Options: Customizing a PRF File.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/ork2003/HA011403051033.aspx